# I lost access to the review queues?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reviewing

I've been trying to check the review queues more often lately, and this last time I checked, I received a message stating I have no review queues available:

[image: Screenshot of review queue error message.]

---

**Update 1**: If I navigate to the queue itself, I'm told my daily vote limit has been reached:

[image: Screenshot of queue page.]

---

What would've caused this? How do I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you navigate directly to the queue itself? (eg. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/)

Comment: @Someone_Evil it appears to be because I've reached my daily vote limit.

Comment: I just found that possibility too and was about to ask you about it :)  I'll write up an answer so it gets documented fully

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Since you've used up your daily votes, First Posts and Late Answer queues are hidden from you

Because one of the key actions for the First Posts and Late Answer queues is to vote on them (in addition to whatever other actions are appropriate), those queues are apparently hidden when you've exhausted your daily votes. And there's apparently no message on the drop-down to explain this, nor a link to help you find that information. I've posted a [feature request about that on Main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368185/681403).

As for getting your queues back; you only need to wait until UTC midnight for your vote limit to refresh.

This is not well documented, but there's an [answer on Main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315000/681403) which describes this (ignore the rest of that Q&A - including comments - this dropdown message used to be shown on review bans (now suspensions) but [isn't any more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351118/681403))